# iframe within iframe cant find element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, automation

Currently trying to find an element that is located in an iframe that is within another iframe. I have not been successful in locating the element. To add an extra challenge the first iframe doesnt contain an ID or Name.

[image]

**My current code looks like this:**

```
    //Open Statement Screen
    [Test, Category("Smoke Test")]
    public void StatementsDisplay()
    {
        var statementsPage = new StatementsPage(driver);
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

        //Click link to Statements page
        statementsPage.statementsLink.Click();

        //Waits for and switches to iframe then verifies element is present
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'/eStatements/eStatements.aspx?internalNavHidden=true&internalThemeName=connect')]")));
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.Id("cphPageContent_EstatementFrame")));
        Assert.IsTrue(statementsPage.pinField.Displayed);
    }
```

**Here is the error:**

[image]

**StatementsPage.get_pinField() line 19:**

```
public IWebElement pinField => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id,'pin')]"));
```

**SmokeTests`1.StatementsDisplay() line 155:**

```
Assert.IsTrue(statementsPage.pinField.Displayed);
```

Comment: What error it threw ? `webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'/eStatements/eStatements')]")));` - try this and let us know if this works

Comment: @cruisepandey I tried that and it didnt work.... I have edited my question with the error and more lines of code.

Comment: are `//iframe[contains(@src,'/eStatements/eStatements')]` and `cphPageContent_EstatementFrame` here not changing and unique locators?

Answer (score 0):

When I achieve the same problem as you I did this:

```
# Get the first iframe
iframe = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
# Put driver on root
browser.switch_to.default_content()
# Move to first iframe
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
# Search second iframe
iframe_2 = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
# Move to the second iframe
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe_2)
# Search element inside second iframe
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath"))).click()
```

It works very good for me on Python 3